# How two version of code exists in SVN?

Tags: svn, merge, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm new to svn and trying to understand it's concepts. But I'm struggling to understand this logic.

Lets say I'm working on one project and In that project there are three developers and all are working on their split work. So for that we have created three branches for all of them.

Once work is done, whole branches committed by individual developers and merged all code into trunk. Upto here I have one doubt is , when we commit changes into branch, the code stays stable in branch or moved to trunk automatically once commit or Is it required to move committed branch code to trunk ?

Secondly, Once its in trunk, lets say I have A version of my code. Now I want to make some changes into version A. I will checkout i.e I will take a copy of version A to my local machine and once its over I will put back into trunk for version B.

Here my question is does trunk stores both version of same code i.e version A and version B separately ?

Correct my understanding please ..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when we commit changes into branch, the code stays stable in branch or
>   moved to trunk automatically once commit or Is it required to move
>   committed branch code to trunk ?

The code committed to a branch stays in this branch. You need to perform [automatic reintegrate merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.reintegrate) to trunk to "move" this code.

> Secondly, Once its in trunk, lets say I have A version of my code. Now
>   I want to make some changes into version A. I will checkout i.e I will
>   take a copy of version A to my local machine and once its over I will
>   put back into trunk for version B.

I do not understand what exactly you mean by "version A" and "version B". Maybe you want to create separate branches for these "versions"?

> Here my question is does trunk stores both version of same code i.e
>   version A and version B separately?

Those version A and B can have separate branches. Or you can address these versions by revision number.

I would recommend that you read the documentation:

- [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) is a great resource of information about Subversion and version control in general. It will help you familiarize yourself with common terminology and concepts of SVN and version control. Now your questions are a bit unclear.
- [TortoiseSVN manual](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html) will help you gain knowledge of the GUI client and perform most common SVN operations with its help.

Comment: @baherp...Here version A and Version B means,  when the first time I had merged the code into trunk lets say Alpha version. But when I took same code and modified completely and merged into trunk again, then lets say beta version. So at the end would be I able to get both version alpha and beta separately from trunk ? If yest, what needs to be done to achieve this, like you said something revision number. What's that ?

Comment: @JonyLinux use tags to mark those versions: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.tags.html